# How to iterate an array to count elements PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I wanna know how to iterate an array to count elements in PHP, I've trying next,

```
foreach ($items as $item) {
                $tm[$item->provider->name] = [];
                foreach ($items as $item) {
                    $tm[$item->provider->name][$item->product->brand->name] = isset($tm[$item->provider->name][$item->product->brand->name]) ? $tm[$item->provider->name][$item->product->brand->name] + 1 : $tm[$item->provider->name][$item->product->brand->name] = 1;
                }
            }
```

But I get a wrong result, I get an array but I get a very high number count as if iterated many timesmany times

The structure of the array is as follows

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "product": {
        "id": 1,
        "brand": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "iphone"
        }
    },
    "provider": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "at&t"
    }
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "product": {
        "id": 2,
        "brand": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "iphone"
        }
    },
    "provider": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "at&t"
    }
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "product": {
        "id": 3,
        "brand": {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "iphone"
        }
    },
    "provider": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "t-mobile"
    }
}]
```

Comment: Your code does a lot of things wrong, the two most glaring errors are a) that you iterate over the array twice, nested - i.e you are doing squared more iteration than needed; B) you use a trinary as the expression to assign to the field, but the right side of the trinary is also an assignment?!

Comment: Somewhat related: [Count unique rows of data based on the values in two columns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42182686/2943403) Also related: [Count values based on multiple key values in php](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39034047/2943403), and [Count entries grouped by id and month from denormalized database](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71141553/2943403)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you are trying to count the `product->brand->name` values for each `provider->name`. You can do that using this code:

```php
$tm = array();
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $product = $item->product->brand->name;
    $provider = $item->provider->name;
    $tm[$provider][$product] = ($tm[$provider][$product] ?? 0) + 1;
}

print_r($tm);
```

Output (for your sample data):

```
Array
(
    [at&t] => Array
        (
            [iphone] => 2
        )
    [t-mobile] => Array
        (
            [iphone] => 1
        )
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/tDnZW)

Answer (score -1):

From your code example you apparently want to count how many occurrences are for each "thing" in your array, otherwise `count()` would have probably sufficed...

Though you are doing a lot of work to pre-init the counting array - that is completely unneeded: read about auto-vivifcation.

Code like so would probably suffice (I'm not following your example code here - you'd need to work out to your needs):

```php
$counters = [];
foreach ($items as $item)
  @$counters[$item->name][$item->model]++;
```

Comment: PHP is going to cry foul at the `++` applied to undeclared elements.

Comment: You are right - `++` can auto-vivify unset field into an `int` but can't do an unset field to array with a field. Fortunately, `+=` does work as we need. I fixed my answer.

Comment: This answer does not appear to be fixed.  The addition assignment operator also requires the variable to be declared in advance.  Write yourself a 3v4l.org demo to prove it to yourself.

Comment: A) @mickmackusa, give it a refresh; B) I have verified that this works in PHP 8.1 CLI.

Comment: @mickmackusa - I take it back: `++` works just as well, it just shows notices (or warnings, depending on your PHP version) about missing keys. I silenced them with `@` and it works fine.

Comment: I will not be upvoting an answer that recommends a hack like the stfu operator.  Nick's answer demonstrates a professional technique.

Comment: Legit opinion, I guess.